# Rails error (Couldn't find User with 'id'=logout) with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, webrick

what are the possible solutions for (Couldn't find User with 'id'=logout)?. I appreciate any input. All what I could find is a reference to a bug. Thanks in advance.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=logout):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

users_controller.rb

```
line 15: def show
line 16:   @user = User.find(params[:id])
line 17: end
```

routes.rb

```
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

views/layout/application.html.erb

```
          <% if logged_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to current_user.name, current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post more or your code. Like your link to `logout` in view

Comment: I added the relevant logout view. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post your entire routes.rb and the output of `rake routes` please?

Comment: try replacing that line in routes file by this `delete ':id', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :logout`

Answer (score 0):

So you're clicking the URL generated by `logout_path` (so, `/logout`?) and instead of going to your `sessions#destroy` action it's going to your `users#show` action and failing because your action is being given the string `"logout"` in `params[:id]`

This is going to be caused by another route earlier in your `routes.rb` file that is shadowing the route that you've shown in your question.  Eg. you might have something like this:

```
resources :users, path: '/'
```

...or perhaps you have a normal users resource but then your `delete` line nested inside a users namespace or something:

```
resources :users

# then lower in your file something like...
namespace :users do
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

#### Update

Neither of those things lead to exactly what you're seeing, so if the above doesn't point you in the right direction then please add to your question your full `config/routes.rb` file and/or the output of `rake routes`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Firefox wasn't sending http delete request when clicking logout, but a get, so had to add one line to routes.rb to handle http get request for logout. Special thanks goes to John!

Comment: Thanks everyone! if you have other solutions please share. Thanks again.